# angularjs $templateCache not available before route resolve

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive outside of ng-view, and also set up route `resolve` with deferred object. However, this prevent me using `templateUrl` for the directive outside ng-view. When I tried to call `$templateCache.get()` before route resolve, it says `undefined`.

I don't know if is this by design? Or a bug?